# Should I use SVG to fix pixelated circle in logo instead of PNG?

Tags: logos

I create a logo with a circle and because it has transparent area, I used png. The thing is that on my website it doesn't look smooth. There is a lot of aliasing... Should I use svg for logo? Is it well supported by browser?

[image: image of a logo made up of a circle with the letter 'N' in it]

Comment: You have probably saved your image as an 8-bit PNG instead of a 24-bit one. Nevertheless, this question is off topic for this site and probably belongs better on the Graphic Design Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about visual design and file formats only.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought any problems you're having with the .png file are related to the original image itself and the quality of its conversion to .png, rather than a problem with the .png format.

In answer to your question though, Safari, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge, Chrome, and Opera all offer SVG rendering support.

If it was me, though, I would first try to see if you can get it to look as you want in PNG format first, only because PNG is more widely supported generally.

Comment: weird, because I used Illustrator and convert into png. Will see tomorrow if I can fixe that.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific example's lack of smoothness is not because png renders bad. It is just because you did not exported your png file in a correct way.

If you have your original logo in vectors turn anti-alias on. In some rare cases you can export it two times larger and resample it on Photoshop or Gimp. If you do not have the original in vectors... **you need to draw it again** anyway. (Inserting a bitmap inside Ilustrator wil not magicly convert it to vectors)

For something like a Logo, you can use either format, but I would only use SVG if I really need to scale an image. Some map, some blueprints, some diagrams.